# using r.js optimization to optimize modules

Tags: node.js, requirejs, r.js

If I use Modules options, I see the whole files are copied and I am not sure how to use a single optimized file.
I can build a file with references to JS files and use that file to generate a single file.
But using Modules option, I see only the source files are copied directly and I see no optimization....any idea on how to use modules option and optimize it?

Here is the snippet...

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    dir: "app/main-built-125",
    modules: [{
            name: "scripts/Address/AddressList"
        }, {
            name: "scripts/Office/OfficeDetails"
        }],
    paths: {
        jquery: 'empty'
    },
    fileExclusionRegExp: /^\./,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `include` option to specify which dependencies to include with the module.

Note that by default dependencies of the defined modules (the one set as `name`) should be fetched and included in the builded file (Of course, as long as they're defined in the `define()` deps array).

Comment: Thanks..But I understand how these modules work..When I say addresslist, all the dependencies of addresslist will be built into addresslist. I guess that works good for multipage apps. So, I switched to name and out parameters for singlepage apps.